# Can I have the className of a leaflet divIcon inside the <style scoped> section of a vue component?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet

I have a Vue 2 sample project at https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test

When [declaring the divIcon](https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test/blob/main/src/components/LeafletTest.vue), I have:

```
      const cloudIcon = L.divIcon({
        html: thecloud,
        className: 'my-custom-icons',
        iconSize: [size, size],
        iconAnchor: [size/2, size/2]
      })
```

and, for leaflet to see the `my-custom-icons` style, I wrote:

```
<style scoped>
  #mapContainer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
  }
</style>

<style>
  .my-custom-icons {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

I would like the style section to look like:

```
<style scoped>
  #mapContainer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
  }

  .my-custom-icons {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

But when I place `my-custom-icons` inside of the components scoped section, the divIcon cannot find it.

Can I organize my style section like this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [DeepSelectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors).

```
#mapContainer >>> .my-custom-icons {
  background-color: red;
}
```